# Conditional Statement as Hierarchy jQuery

Tags: jquery, object, css-selectors, hierarchy

Is there a way to make jQuery use objects in a conditional statement as an object in a hierarchy. For Example, I want to validate that something exist then tell it to do something just using the this selector.

Like this

```
if ($(".tnImg").length) {
```

//i have to declare what object I am targeting here to get this to work

```
            $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.5,   
            }, 200 );
  }
```

Is there a way to get jQuery to do this? 
I guess theres not a huge benefit but i still am curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, if nothing is found, then nothing happens, for example:

```
$(".tnImg").animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 200 );
```

This won't error, if it doesn't find anything with `class="tnImg"` it simply won't run on any elements.  This is one of the fundamentals that makes jQuery so terse :)

If you wanted to do lots with the object, this would let you use it as `$(this)` for each one:

```
$(".tnImg").each(function() {
  //$(this) is the current class="tnImg" element, this code runs for each one
  $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 200 );
});
```

Comment: ok so your saying i can use the each function rather the finding out if it exist. and the code will still work. Then I can use the hierarchy. Now let say if I have more parameters to the animate function plus multiple events with different animations to each event.

If i use the each function will it bypass the code inside the callback rather then running the code even when the element is not there.

Comment: @Jacob - Can you post an example of what you *want* to do?  It's often easier to just illustrate how to do an example :)  If you call an animation, the callback runs for **each** element that was animated (they all animate individually).  If the selector found no elements, then none are animated and the callback wouldn't run even once, make sense?

Comment: @Jacob - No problem, that's what SO is for, is you have more questions feel free, I'll answer if I can.